# Bootstrap 3 blurry font and glyphicons

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange display of Bootstrap 3 fonts and glyphicons.
The bitmaps and the font is looking some kind of blurry. The effect is visible everywhere, so I attached an example of the navbar items.
This happens only on desktops with FF and Chrome.
On mobile devices everything is crispy as it should be.
Has anyone an idea what is happening here?

[image: Bootstrap menu entries]

Thanks in advance,
Dirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a feature of bootstrap 3/ 4 on different desktop browsers. There are some workarounds proposed but as browser developers wont fix this issue in webkit since 2016. Read more in this of course still open issue from 2018:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/27955open
Possible workarounds:

- Adapted CSS for different target resolutions/browser combinations
- Trying to tweak fonts or use different fonts and include all possible
  formats for the most affected targets
- Edit (tweak) bootstrap sass    and compile custom version

But unluckely no easy way

Comment: Yes, also for me the effect looks like an artefact of zooming the page. And the screenshot in the issue of bootstrap shows the same effects. But I do not zoom into the page to produce the problem, the zoom level is 100%. It looks like the page is zoomed by some percents during rendering. This is just an idea and I'm not sure if thhis can happen under normal circumstances?

Comment: As discribed in the article this "zooming" is not done by the user, but by the rendering engine of the browser (webkit-based) Since 90% of users use mobile devices to surf, desktop development is not in focus any longer. Like I wrote if you have a fixed resolution in mind (target device is known) you can optimize to it, if not...

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. But it's no good for the problem itself ;-)

Comment: See edit - please mark as "solved" so others find it even if it is unsolvable in an easy way

Answer (score 0):

Сheck your own CSS. However, have a look here: https://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3

Comment: I already stripped dow the whole page to somewhat "bare metal". I removed all CSS code apart from bootstrap and it stays the same. Appying the suggested CSS style from the link above did not change the display. My hope was that this is some kind of a known rendering problem...